# Problems when starting react packages in meteor

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I meet a lot of errors when added react to package file for meteor. Then I found this solution. And it works hopefully. Please if you know better solution, could you provide it. Because I am newbee and do not fully understand consequenses of using different versions.

meteor npm install --save react react-dom react-addons-transition-group react-addons-css-transition-group react-addons-linked-state-mixin react-addons-create-fragment react-addons-update react-addons-pure-render-mixin react-addons-test-utils react-addons-perf

npm install --save-dev react@15.4.2

npm install --save-dev react-dom@15.4.2

npm install --save-dev react-addons-test-utils

Comment: Does the above described install still throws errors or does it start? If there are still errors please add them here. Also if there are no known issue you could use `@latest` for getting the latest package version

Comment: The tutorial that I was using, used React, version 1.2.1. It has to be the same version to work properly. Errors were related to transtion packages and other React related problems.